# How can I redirect all files in a folder to another directory except a few files using mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a situation where an entire folder's contents are no longer needed and will be redirected to the home page, **except 6 or so files**. The folder holds over 300 files, so individual redirects:

```
redirect 301 /folder/file.html http://www.domain.tld/
redirect 301 /folder/file2.html http://www.domain.tld/
redirect 301 /folder/file3.html http://www.domain.tld/
```

This would take quite a long time. I have some time before needing this done, and would like to know if anyone knows a good way to achieve this by using a little regex with mod_rewrite.

For optimum understanding for all who may use the potential correct answer, lets say the files that we don't want to redirect are:

```
/folder/stay1.html
/folder/stay2.html
/folder/stay3.html
```

Thanks in advance for this wonderful community of very knowledgeable people helping those of us who still have a few things to learn!

*Edit*

Is it possible to achieve this and keep the base url of the folder?

```
/folder/
/folder/index.html
```

I tried the following without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder(/|/index.html|/stay1.html|/stay2.html|/stay3.html|/etc.html)
RewriteRule ^/?folder/ http://www.domain.tld/ [L,R=301]
```

*Edit* Correct Answer

A big thanks goes out to [Jon Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin) for the answer.

The correct method to redirect all files of a `/folder/` except a few, while still allowing access to `/folder/` is:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow /folder/ to remain accessible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/$

# Allow specified files to remain accessible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/(index.html|stay1.html|stay2.html|stay3.html|etc.html)

# Redirect all non-specified files to home page
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.+)$ http://www.domain.tld/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This probably belongs on http://superuser.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, you can create exception conditions to the redirect, try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/(index.html|stay1.html|stay2.html|stay3.html|etc.html)
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.+)$ http://www.domain.tld/ [L,R=301]
```

So anything that's in the list: `(stay1.html|stay2.html|stay3.html|etc.html)` will fail the condition and the redirect won't happen. Otherwise, anything starting with `/folder/` will get redirected to `http://www.domain.tld/`.

Note that if you have mod_alias redirects intermixed, they may interfere with each other.

Comment: I think you have to replace your last `RewriteCond` with `RewriteRule`

Comment: what if I still have /index.html, which is usually accessed by "/folder/"?

Comment: @hdavis84 That will get redirected too, the `^/?folder/` regular expression matches anything that **starts** with `/folder/`, which obviously includes `/folder/index.html`.

Comment: this code definitely works well for what I want it to achieve, however, I may have to create a file in the root of the site, such as domain.tld/folder.html if I cannot retain being able to visit domain.tld/folder/

Comment: @hdavis84 `^/?folder/`` will never match `/folder.html`

Comment: is there a way to redirect all pages except the few, and still be able to visit /folder/ ?

Comment: @hdavis84 Sure, edited the answer to include `index.html` in the exclusion and ensure that there's something *after* the `/folder/`.

Comment: maybe another `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/$` or something like it?

Comment: awesome, I just figured it out, thanks a ton for the help. I couldn't have done nearly as quick (prolly not within a week if I had to research regex with .htaccess on my own) without you

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/?folder/(?!(stay1\.html|stay2\.html|stay3\.html)) http://domain.tld
```

An alternative mod-rewrite solution would be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(stay1\.html|stay2\.html|stay3\.html)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?folder/.* http://domain.tld
```

The first rule catches all the exceptions, the L flag ensures no further processing takes place in this pass, and the `-` instructs the engine not to rewrite, ensuring no further passes are made. Anything not caught by the first rule is redirected by the second rule.

Comment: what if the index.html file is still going to be accessed after the mass redirects? It's usually accessed by "/folder/"